# Bootstrap multi-column checkbox doesn't line up

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I'm trying to use bootstrap to create multi-column checkbox lists. But the first item in the first column is not lining up with the rest.

code: http://jsfiddle.net/04pgkkfv/1/

```
<div class="row">
  <ul class="list-group row" data-bind="foreach: availableProgramIndexes">
    <li class="checkbox list-group-item col-sm-2">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: $data" /><span data-bind="text: $data"></span></label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
  var BaseVM = function() {
    var that = {};
    return that;
  };

  var TestVM = function() {
    var that = BaseVM();

    that.availableProgramIndexes = ko.observableArray([]);
    return that;
  };

  var vm = TestVM();
  vm.availableProgramIndexes.push('123 456');
  vm.availableProgramIndexes.push('123 456');
  vm.availableProgramIndexes.push('123 456');
  vm.availableProgramIndexes.push('123 456');
  vm.availableProgramIndexes.push('123 456');
  vm.availableProgramIndexes.push('123 456');
  vm.availableProgramIndexes.push('123 456');
  vm.availableProgramIndexes.push('123 456');
  vm.availableProgramIndexes.push('123 456');
  vm.availableProgramIndexes.push('123 456');
  vm.availableProgramIndexes.push('123 456');
  vm.availableProgramIndexes.push('123 456');
  vm.availableProgramIndexes.push('123 456');
  vm.availableProgramIndexes.push('123 456');
  vm.availableProgramIndexes.push('123 456');
  vm.availableProgramIndexes.push('123 456');
  vm.availableProgramIndexes.push('123 456');
  vm.availableProgramIndexes.push('123 456');
  vm.availableProgramIndexes.push('123 456');
  vm.availableProgramIndexes.push('123 456');
  vm.availableProgramIndexes.push('123 456');
  vm.availableProgramIndexes.push('123 456');
  vm.availableProgramIndexes.push('123 456');
  vm.availableProgramIndexes.push('123 456');
  vm.availableProgramIndexes.push('123 456');
  vm.availableProgramIndexes.push('123 456');
  ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing default Bootstrap CSS in action. Either you override styles as per @TSV but watch out for side-effects in other usages. Or update *just* the HTML to play nice with Bootstrap:

```
<li class="list-group-item col-sm-2">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: $data" />
      <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
</li>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kj1L9jp6/)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to fix it

```
ul.row {
  margin:-10px auto auto auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/04pgkkfv/3/):

```
.checkbox.list-group-item {
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```